# Can I trust new articles in a high-impact journal with abnormal number of corrections for older ones?

Tags: peer-review, journals, bibliometrics

Currently I survey new literature by subscribing to the RSS feed of high-impact journals. Especially for the journal *nature communications* (IP > 12) I see much much higher number of  correction articles than in any other journal, also other journals of the *nature publishing group*.

How should I judge this? Especially when mostly author corrections? Or can this be explained by factors like:

- pure online journal, corrections in printed journals are less common or editing more thorough
- many submissions and articles published im comparison to average journal
- open access

So, in other high impact journals from science, APS, AIP, ACS this doesn't seem to happen.

As the reviewers of all journals are likely and mostly voluntary academics, I'm really wondering what is so special/the problem with this high-impact journal.

[image]

Comment: Did you consider reading the article and the corrections? That normally helps to decide if it is thrustworthy.

Comment: Sorry, but either I misworded our you misread my question, which is about the trustworthiness of the journal publishing so many corrections and especially articles in that journals without such corrections (but probably soon to come given above number in the screenshot). I will edit title...

Comment: When I compare this to your answer to a Covid question you wrote here too, you seem to be on a vendetta against Nature (and Science). One wonders why.

Comment: There is definitively variation in how willing different journals are to publish corrections. I'll note that many of [these author corrections](https://www.nature.com/ncomms/articles?type=author-correction) seem rather trivial, and that, [since 2018, APS](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.120.010002) will make minor corrections without issuing similar correction articles.

Comment: Communications and other rapid publications are likely more prone to corrections. That is why they are communications, not regular articles. They have their place to get stuff out fast, and refine later.

Comment: the 4th and 5th comment are possible answers and yes the corrections seem minor/trivial mostly. The 3rd comment is just clownish or from a nature/science employee. The last activity I had on this site was months ago, lol...